How can I use my own MNIST formatted dataset instead of the default MNIST dataset in tensorflow?
I am working on a Deep Convolutional GAN using tensorflow to generate handwritten images. I have a script that can generate images using the MNIST dataset, and I have a dataset that is formatted, as far as I can tell, exactly like the mnist dataset. However, I am having a hard time dropping in my dataset instead of the MNIST one and am having a hard time finding the documentation to do so. The dataset is called digits_x_test.npy and this is the function I use to load the MNIST dataset.
def load_data():
  (images, _), (_, _) = tensorflow.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
  images = images.reshape(images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
  images = images.astype('float32')
  images = (images - 127.5) / 127.5
  return tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(images).shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

I have also included the complete code for both the GAN and how I created my dataset for reference, but I don't believe it will be necessary.
GAN Code:
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import uuid
import os
import numpy as np

# Initialize variables
NUM_EPOCHS = 50
BUFFER_SIZE = 30000
BATCH_SIZE = 28
NOISE_DIMENSION = 75
UNIQUE_RUN_ID = str(uuid.uuid4())
PRINT_STATS_AFTER_BATCH = 50
OPTIMIZER_LR = 0.0002
OPTIMIZER_BETAS = (0.5, 0.999)
WEIGHT_INIT_STDDEV = 0.02

# Initialize loss function, init schema and optimizers
cross_entropy_loss = tensorflow.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
weight_init = tensorflow.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=WEIGHT_INIT_STDDEV)
generator_optimizer = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(OPTIMIZER_LR, \
  beta_1=OPTIMIZER_BETAS[0], beta_2=OPTIMIZER_BETAS[1])
discriminator_optimizer = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(OPTIMIZER_LR, \
  beta_1=OPTIMIZER_BETAS[0], beta_2=OPTIMIZER_BETAS[1])


def make_directory_for_run():
  """ Make a directory for this training run. """
  print(f'Preparing training run {UNIQUE_RUN_ID}')
  if not os.path.exists('./runs'):
    os.mkdir('./runs')
  os.mkdir(f'./runs/{UNIQUE_RUN_ID}')


def generate_image(generator, epoch = 0, batch = 0):
  """ Generate subplots with generated examples. """
  images = []
  noise = generate_noise(BATCH_SIZE)
  images = generator(noise, training=False)
  plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
  for i in range(16):
    # Get image and reshape
    image = images[i]
    image = np.reshape(image, (28, 28))
    # Plot
    plt.subplot(4, 4, i+1)
    plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
    plt.axis('off')
  if not os.path.exists(f'./runs/{UNIQUE_RUN_ID}/images'):
    os.mkdir(f'./runs/{UNIQUE_RUN_ID}/images')
  plt.savefig(f'./runs/{UNIQUE_RUN_ID}/images/epoch{epoch}_batch{batch}.jpg')


def load_data():
  (images, _), (_, _) = tensorflow.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
  images = images.reshape(images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
  images = images.astype('float32')
  images = (images - 127.5) / 127.5
  return tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(images).shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

def create_generator():
  """ Create Generator """
  generator = tensorflow.keras.Sequential()
  # Input block
  generator.add(layers.Dense(7*7*128, use_bias=False, input_shape=(NOISE_DIMENSION,), \
    kernel_initializer=weight_init))
  generator.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
  generator.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
  # Reshape 1D Tensor into 3D
  generator.add(layers.Reshape((7, 7, 128)))
  # First upsampling block
  generator.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(56, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False, \
    kernel_initializer=weight_init))
  generator.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
  generator.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
  # Second upsampling block
  generator.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(28, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False, \
    kernel_initializer=weight_init))
  generator.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
  generator.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
  # Third upsampling block: note tanh, specific for DCGAN
  generator.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh', \
    kernel_initializer=weight_init))
  # Return generator
  return generator


def generate_noise(number_of_images = 1, noise_dimension = NOISE_DIMENSION):
  """ Generate noise for number_of_images images, with a specific noise_dimension """
  return tensorflow.random.normal([number_of_images, noise_dimension])
  

def create_discriminator():
  """ Create Discriminator """
  discriminator = tensorflow.keras.Sequential()
  # First Convolutional block
  discriminator.add(layers.Conv2D(28, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
                                    input_shape=[28, 28, 1], kernel_initializer=weight_init))
  discriminator.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
  discriminator.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
  # Second Convolutional block
  discriminator.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', kernel_initializer=weight_init))
  discriminator.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
  discriminator.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
  # Flatten and generate output prediction
  discriminator.add(layers.Flatten())
  discriminator.add(layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer=weight_init, activation='sigmoid'))
  # Return discriminator
  return discriminator


def compute_generator_loss(predicted_fake):
  """ Compute cross entropy loss for the generator """
  return cross_entropy_loss(tensorflow.ones_like(predicted_fake), predicted_fake)


def compute_discriminator_loss(predicted_real, predicted_fake):
  """ Compute discriminator loss """
  loss_on_reals = cross_entropy_loss(tensorflow.ones_like(predicted_real), predicted_real)
  loss_on_fakes = cross_entropy_loss(tensorflow.zeros_like(predicted_fake), predicted_fake)
  return loss_on_reals + loss_on_fakes


def save_models(generator, discriminator, epoch):
  """ Save models at specific point in time. """
  tensorflow.keras.models.save_model(
    generator,
    f'./runs/{UNIQUE_RUN_ID}/generator_{epoch}.keras',
    overwrite=True,
    include_optimizer=True,
    save_format=None,
    #signatures=None,
    #options=None
  )
  tensorflow.keras.models.save_model(
    discriminator,
    f'./runs/{UNIQUE_RUN_ID}/discriminator{epoch}.keras',
    overwrite=True,
    include_optimizer=True,
    save_format=None,
    #signatures=None,
    #options=None
  )
  

def print_training_progress(batch, generator_loss, discriminator_loss):
  """ Print training progress. """
  print('Losses after mini-batch %5d: generator %e, discriminator %e' %
        (batch, generator_loss, discriminator_loss))


@tensorflow.function
def perform_train_step(real_images, generator, discriminator):
  """ Perform one training step with Gradient Tapes """
  # Generate noise
  noise = generate_noise(BATCH_SIZE)
  # Feed forward and loss computation for one batch
  with tensorflow.GradientTape() as discriminator_tape, \
      tensorflow.GradientTape() as generator_tape:
        # Generate images
        generated_images = generator(noise, training=True)
        # Discriminate generated and real images
        discriminated_generated_images = discriminator(generated_images, training=True)
        discriminated_real_images = discriminator(real_images, training=True)
        # Compute loss
        generator_loss = compute_generator_loss(discriminated_generated_images)
        discriminator_loss = compute_discriminator_loss(discriminated_real_images, discriminated_generated_images)
  # Compute gradients
  generator_gradients = generator_tape.gradient(generator_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
  discriminator_gradients = discriminator_tape.gradient(discriminator_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)
  # Optimize model using gradients
  generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(generator_gradients, generator.trainable_variables))
  discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(discriminator_gradients, discriminator.trainable_variables))
  # Return generator and discriminator losses
  return (generator_loss, discriminator_loss)
        
  
def train_gan(num_epochs, image_data, generator, discriminator):
  """ Train the GAN """
  # Perform one training step per batch for every epoch
  for epoch_no in range(num_epochs):
    num_batches = image_data.__len__()
    print(f'Starting epoch {epoch_no+1} with {num_batches} batches...')
    batch_no = 0
    # Iterate over batches within epoch
    for batch in image_data:
      generator_loss, discriminator_loss = perform_train_step(batch, generator, discriminator)
      batch_no += 1
      # Print statistics and generate image after every n-th batch
      if batch_no % PRINT_STATS_AFTER_BATCH == 0:
        print_training_progress(batch_no, generator_loss, discriminator_loss)
        generate_image(generator, epoch_no, batch_no)
    # Save models on epoch completion.
    save_models(generator, discriminator, epoch_no)
  # Finished :-)
  print(f'Finished unique run {UNIQUE_RUN_ID}')


def run_gan():
  """ Initialization and training """
  # Make run directory
  make_directory_for_run()
  # Set random seed
  tensorflow.random.set_seed(42)
  # Get image data
  data = load_data()
  # Create generator and discriminator
  generator = create_generator()
  discriminator = create_discriminator()
  # Train the GAN
  print('Training GAN ...')
  train_gan(NUM_EPOCHS, data, generator, discriminator)
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  run_gan()


  

Dataset Creation Code:
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageEnhance, ImageOps
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import cv2

input_folder = '/home/REDACTED/Documents/DeepConvolutiuonalGAN/input/'

filename = input_folder+'input.png'
image = Image.open(filename)

def show(img, figsize=(8, 4), title=None):
    plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    plt.imshow(img)
    if title:
        plt.title(title)
    plt.show()

#show(image)

print(f'Image details')
print(f'Format {image.format}')
print(f'Size {image.size}')
print(f'Mode {image.mode}')

bw_image = image.convert(mode='L') #L is 8-bit black-and-white image mode
#show(bw_image, figsize=(12, 12))
bw_image = ImageEnhance.Contrast(bw_image).enhance(1.5)
#show(bw_image, figsize=(12, 12))

SIZE = 30
samples = [] #array to store cut images
for digit, y in enumerate(range(0, bw_image.height, SIZE)):
    #print('Cutting digit:', digit)
    cuts=[]
    for x in range(0, bw_image.width, SIZE):
        cut = bw_image.crop(box=(x, y, x+SIZE, y+SIZE))
        cuts.append(cut)
    samples.append(cuts)
print(f'Cut {len(samples)*len(samples[0])} images total.')


f = plt.figure(figsize=(18,2))
ax = f.subplots(1, 6)
for i, n in enumerate(np.random.randint(0, len(samples), size=6)):
    m = (np.random.randint(0, len(samples[n])))
    #ax[i].imshow(samples[n][m])
    #ax[i].set_title(f'Digit: [{n}]')
#plt.show()


sample = samples[7][14]
#show(sample, figsize=(2, 2))
# Inver sample, get bbox and display all that stuff.
inv_sample = ImageOps.invert(sample)
bbox = inv_sample.getbbox()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2, 2))
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])

#ax.imshow(inv_sample)
rect = patches.Rectangle(
    (bbox[0], bbox[3]), bbox[2]-bbox[0], -bbox[3]+bbox[1]-1,
    fill=False, alpha=1, edgecolor='w')
ax.add_patch(rect)
plt.show()

crop = inv_sample.crop(bbox)
#show(crop, title='Image cropped to bounding box')

#resize back
new_size = 28
delta_w = new_size - crop.size[0]
delta_h = new_size - crop.size[1]
padding = (delta_w//2, delta_h//2, delta_w-(delta_w//2), delta_h-(delta_h//2))
new_im = ImageOps.expand(crop, padding)
#show(new_im, title='Resized and centered to 28x28')


def resize_and_center(sample, new_size=28):
    inv_sample = ImageOps.invert(sample)
    bbox = inv_sample.getbbox()
    crop = inv_sample.crop(bbox)
    delta_w = new_size - crop.size[0]
    delta_h = new_size - crop.size[1]
    padding = (delta_w//2, delta_h//2, delta_w-(delta_w//2), delta_h-(delta_h//2))
    return ImageOps.expand(crop, padding)

resized_samples = []
for row in samples:
    resized_samples.append([resize_and_center(sample) for sample in row])
    
    
f = plt.figure(figsize=(18,2))
ax = f.subplots(1, 6)
for i, n in enumerate(np.random.randint(0, len(resized_samples), size=6)):
    m = (np.random.randint(0, len(resized_samples[n])))
    #ax[i].imshow(resized_samples[n][m])
    #ax[i].set_title(f'Digit: [{n}]')
#plt.show()

preview = Image.new('L', (len(samples[0])*new_size, len(samples)*new_size))


x = 0
y = 0
for row in resized_samples:
    for sample in row:
        preview.paste(sample, (x, y))
        x += new_size
    y+=new_size
    x = 0

#show(preview, figsize=(18,18), title='Processed images')
preview.save('preview.png')

src = cv2.imread('/home/secureboot/Documents/DeepConvolutiuonalGAN/preview.png') 
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

binary_samples = np.array([[sample.getdata() for sample in row] for row in resized_samples])
binary_samples = binary_samples.reshape(len(resized_samples)*len(resized_samples[0]), 28, 28)

show(binary_samples[128], figsize=(1,1))


classes = np.array([[i]*21 for i in range(10)]).reshape(-1)

print(f'X shape: {binary_samples.shape}')
print(f'y shape: {classes.shape}')

xfile = 'digits_x_test.npy'
yfile = 'digits_y_test.npy'
np.save(xfile, binary_samples)
np.save(yfile, classes)

x_test = np.load(xfile)
y_test = np.load(yfile)
x_test.shape, y_test.shape

for i in np.random.randint(x_test.shape[0], size=6):
    show(x_test[i], title=f'Digit [{y_test[i]}]', figsize=(1,1))


I'm having a hard time seeing your problem. Can you describe what errors you encounter/what exacly is not working? "having a hard time" is not very specific.

Yes! I have trouble explaining it myself. When using the MNIST dataset, the program executes as normal. It loads the data and then runs through 50 epochs. Each of these epochs generates a batch of images, progressively more clear up until about epoch 20 where improvements are diminishing. Trying to include my dataset in the load_data function either causes it to still use the MNIST set, or "act" like it's running through the epochs without generating anything. I think I just need the proper syntax to actually load my dataset rather than the MNIST one.

I'd be helpful if you describle more how you create your dataset. There seems to be images, that you are cutting into patches and pad? Did you test the preprocessed images, do they look right, are the values in the correct range? Also, the load_data() function always loads the mnist dataset, I don't know why you expect it to behave different.

@mhenning It is supposed to be a set of handwritten digits 0-9. I used gimp to create 30x30 images, then the Python script converts them to 28x28 single channel images as expected in the MNIST dataset. I have tested and everything is in the correct range and preprocessed correctly. I know the function always loads the mnist data set because of "(images, ), (, ) = tensorflow.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()". I would like to know know what "(images, ), (,) = ? " should be set to to appropriately load my data. I've tried replacing with my .npy file directly, but no training happens.
